# Power Tower leads to a seeming contradiction

Tags: logic, exponentiation

The following contradiction has been bothering me for a day or so and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. You may have seen the infinite power tower problem:

$$ \Large x^{x^{x^{.^{.^.}}}} = 2 $$
$$ \Large x^2 = 2 $$
$$ \Large x = \sqrt{2} $$

Plugging back in the original equation, we have found:

$$ \Large \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{.^{.^.}}}} = 2 $$

However, we also have:

$$ \Large \left( \sqrt{2} ^ {\sqrt{2} }\right)^ \sqrt{2} = \left( \sqrt{2} \right) ^{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}} = \left( \sqrt{2} \right) ^{2} = 2 $$

Therefore

$$ \Large \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{.^{.^.}}}} = \left( \sqrt{2} ^ {\sqrt{2} }\right)^ \sqrt{2} = 2$$

Which seems like a contradiction. Are one or both of my premises false? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $a^{(b^c)}\not=(a^b)^c$ in general: unlike $+$ and $\times$ for example, exponentiation is not [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)! (And when we omit parentheses we associate to the right, that is, the expression "$a^{b^c}$" denotes the *former*.)

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber